# Append and delete elements from a list using property

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my base class is *_mylist* defined as a *list*

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._mylist = list()

    @property
    def mylist(self):
        return self._mylist

    @mylist.setter
    def mylist(self, value):
        self._mylist = value
```

In my derived class Boo

```
class Boo(Foo)
    def __init__(self):
    """   """

    def add_element(self,value):
        Foo.mylist.appened(value)
```

I would like to add and delete elements to *mylist* from *Boo*.
I tried the following:

```
boo = Boo()
boo.add\_element(5)
```

Following exception came up:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'append'
```

At present I modified the setter property of *mylist* to look like:

```
    @mylist.setter
    def mylist(self, value):
        self._mylist.append( value )
```

This allow me to add elements to my *mylist*, but i don't know how to delete elements from it.

Is there a better way of modifing a list in based class from the derived class?

Comment: This is unclear. Exactly how do you want to delete elements from the list?

Comment: There is <property>.deleter (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) but I'm afraid you can't pass it any value.  I don't think it is a good idea to use a property to do this.

Comment: Not really. The `mylist` property already returns the list, which you can modify however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why must change the semantics of setter?

What if just manipulating the list using list's method.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._mylist = list()

    @property
    def mylist(self):
        return self._mylist

    @mylist.setter
    def mylist(self, value):
        self._mylist = value

class Boo(Foo):
    pass

b = Boo()
b.mylist.append(1)  # append directly
b.mylist.append(2)
b.mylist.append(3)
b.mylist.remove(2)  # remove directly
```

Answer (score -3):

Try something like this:

```
@property
def del_element(self, value):
    self._mylist.remove(value)

@property
def add_element(self,value):
    self._mylist.append(value)
```